# Dose google play count insalls out of itself downloads?

Tags: google-play

I recently published my app in google play . The question is how google play show counts ?

1 - All device that have google play installed and my apps too , total count of my apps install will show in play store .

2 - Just all downloads that directly are downloaded from google play will be count .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install count is incremented every time your app is downloaded from Google Play. If someone downloads it from Amazon, or your website, or another source, it will not add to your Google Play installs.